# Can I use HTML DSL to return partial HTML documents?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to build a REST API where I send back some resources using a single HTML element as a representation instead of a complete document. For example instead of

```
<html>

  <body>

   <table>....</table>

  </body>

</html>
```

I just want to return the Table element and its content.

Using the HTML DSL directly with call.respondHtml I only can create complete HTML documents with all the boilerplate.

If I build an XML document by hand and try to send this back with call.respondHtml, I only get an empty HTML document.

Is there a way to do what I want with the HTML DSL in KTOR or do I have to fall back to serializing the XML document by hand? Or would be using a template engine a better way?

Comment: I personally suggest using some template engine instead of `ktor-html-builder` because the latter is too complex and limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your table built as a child template, you can return it as demonstrated below:

```
    call.respondText(
        buildString {
            appendHTML().div {
                insert(TableTemplate(), TemplatePlaceholder())
            }
        }
    )
```

It doesn't build the whole HTML document, but you template is embedded in another div.

Related post: [ktor - is there a way to serialize sub-template Template<FlowContent> to txt/html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034811/ktor-is-there-a-way-to-serialize-sub-template-templateflowcontent-to-txt-htm)

Ktor docs: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Streaming

Comment: That looks promising, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the hint!