# ktor - is there a way to serialize sub-template Template<FlowContent> to txt/html?

Tags: ktor

I am using HTML DSL as the templating engine in my ktor project.
I am trying to send one of the sub-templates Template as a text response (I do not want to send the full HtmlTemplate).

So far I have got below - to make it work I have to wrap my TestTemplate in another div:

```
fun Route.test() {
    get("/test") {
        call.respondText(
            buildString {
                appendHTML().div {
                    insert(TestTemplate(), TemplatePlaceholder())
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This gives me following response (the inner div is my TestTemplate):

```
<div>
  <div>this is the element I want to get, without the outer element</div>
</div>
```

What I would like to get is just the TestTemplate:

```
<div>this is the element I want to get, without the outer element</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve it in ktor using the HTML DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a class for the template with an `HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder>` type parameter instead of `FlowContent` to build a final HTML string without any tags (`FlowContent` inherits `Tag` interface).

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.html.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import kotlinx.html.*
import kotlinx.html.stream.HTMLStreamBuilder

suspend fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 3333) {
        routing {
            get("/test") {
                val builder = StringBuilder()
                val html: HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder> = HTMLStreamBuilder(builder, prettyPrint = true, xhtmlCompatible = false)
                html.insert(TestTemplate(), TemplatePlaceholder())
                call.respondText(html.finalize().toString())
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

class TestTemplate : Template<HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder>> {
    val articleTitle = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    val articleText = Placeholder<FlowContent>()

    override fun HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder>.apply() {
        article {
            h2 {
                insert(articleTitle)
            }
            p {
                insert(articleText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you!

However, this approach means that after I change the template from Template<FlowContent> to Template<HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder>>, I can no longer insert them into the main HTML template, as it expects <FlowContent>. Ideally, I would like to maintain one set of templates, which will initially be inserted into the HTML template and then get any of the child templates with updated content if and as needed.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: If I have my child TestTemplate as FlowContent type, I can by design insert it into my main HomeTemplate that is of type HTML. So the following will work: `class TestTemplate : Template<FlowContent> {override fun FlowContent.apply() {div {+"test" }
}`     `class HomeTemplate() : Template<HTML> { insert(TestTemplate(), TemplatePlaceholder()) }` and finally the route `get("/") { call.respondHtmlTemplate(HomeTemplate()) { } }`. If I change the type to StringBuilder and try to insert the `Template<HTMLStreamBuilder<StringBuilder>>` into my `Template<HTML>` I get an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve both problems. I've created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3474 to address it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep an eye on the yt issue.